# Cakephp best way to store count of children's children

Tags: php, cakephp

OK so if a Student belongs to a Course and Course in turn belongs to a School:

What's the best way to store/get the count of all the Students in a school?

I've recently discovered counterCache but that would only work if Student belonged directly to school. I was thinking of doing a manual count by adding up all the course students in a foreach loop. Is there a neater way?

I'd preferably like to store a student_count field in the school table as that's how I am storing all of the school's other counts (course, module, lecturer), but that may be my fussy OCD kicking in.

Comment: Personally I'd just go with the loop and add up the total.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, try the following code:

```
function test(){
    $this->loadModel('Student');        
    $joins = array(
            array(
                'table' => 'courses',
                'alias'  => 'Course',
                'type'  => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('Course.id = Student.course_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'schools',
                'alias'  => 'School',
                'type'  => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array('School.id = Course.school_id')
            ),
        );

        $school_wise_student_count = $this->Student->find('all', array('fields'=>array('count(Student.id) as total_student','School.name as school_name'), 'joins'=>$joins, 'group'=>array('Course.school_id')));
        pr($school_wise_student_count);
        die;

}
```